# Obtain the gateway address

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I am developing a meshing system.

If an esp32 manages to connect to the WAN, it creates an access point to which other esp32s that could not have connected to the WAN can connect.

So I wrote this:

```
if (!connectToWAN()) {
    connectToESP();
}
```

If the device cannot connect to the WAN, then it will scan for available access points, and if the SSID of the scanned access point starts with "ESP32-", then it will connect to it.

I have no problem at this level, everything is working perfectly. But to send data between devices, I need to make requests, and to make a request, I need the IP address of the esp32 on which I want to send the request (so the IP address of the AP).

Example :

`http.begin("http://192.168.1.78/test");`

Unfortunately, after much research in the header files of the WiFi library, I did not find a function allowing me to retrieve the IP address of the access point on which I am connected.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get it? Thank you

Comment: it is the gateway address

Comment: Thank you, i edited the title of the question !

Comment: `ip = WiFi.gatewayIP();`

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: by default the gateway IP is the same as the IP of the SoftAP. it is possible to configure it to a different IP, but why would one do that.